# PurgeCSS removes third party library css - Laravel Mix / TailwindCSS

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, postcss, tailwind-css

I installed TailwindCSS & PurgeCSS in an existing application that uses custom CSS as well as some third party libraries. I configured PurgeCSS to only purge a single tailwind file but it for some reason removes css selectors from third party libraries, maybe my config is wrong:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix         = require("laravel-mix");
const purgeCss    = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss")
const tailwindCss = require("tailwindcss")

mix.webpackConfig(require("./webpack.parts"));

// Don't want to purge anything under app.scss, it contains custom css &
// current app related stuff
mix.sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css").version();

// I simply want to add tailwind so I can use it in addition to whatever
// css the app currently uses
mix.postCss("resources/sass/tailwind.pcss", "public/css", [
    tailwindCss,
    ...process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [purgeCss(
        {
            content: [
                "./resources/**/*.js",
                "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
            ],

            css: [
                "./public/css/tailwind.css"
            ]
        }
    )] : []
])
```

Tried changing `css` path from `./public/css/tailwind.css` to `./resources/sass/tailwind.pcss` but did not help

**Edit:**
Seems like I had to move out some of the dependency imports from the `app.scss` to get it to work, though I am not sure why:

Added this snippet right before `mix.sass(app.scss)`

```
mix.styles(
    [
        "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.css",
        "./node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
        "./node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css",
    ],
    "public/css/vendors.css"
).version()
```

Comment: what does this do `mix.webpackConfig(require("./webpack.parts"));`?

Comment: @AndySong it creates aliases so that I can import files easier, for example instead of doing `../../../components/foo.js` I can do `@components/foo.js` using `path.resolve`

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce your bug, this code works perfectly for me.

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
    content: [
      'resources/**/*.blade.php',
    ],
    defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
  })

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version();


mix.postCss('resources/sass/tailwind.pcss', 'public/css', [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    ...process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? [purgecss]
    : []
  ])
```

Comment: Strange, it seems that it removes bootstrap related classes from my app.scss because app.scss has import for bootstrap